# How to get live current updated data from a page in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to create a page where some one see the live debates which is a debate forum on another page.

How can I get this? Can anybody help me How I would be able to do so? I know this can be done by jQuery but do not know How.

I have one page for debate..[here](http://africanbreed.com/main/topics/)
Second Page to show the current debate..[here](http://africanbreed.com/main/home/)

Can I put this debate content from first page to a div on second page?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Explain more your quest for Good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send request after Interval using ajax:

Simple example:

```
updateData();//calling function for first time

function updateData(){
        /* ajax request*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "your url",
            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){ /* called when request to request completes */
                setTimeout(
                    updateData, /* Request next update */
                    1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
                );
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: listen listen please.. I am editing my question for more explaination .. yes , I need this.. Please see my updated question I am giving something more. 
And what I need to put in the url:"your url"

Comment: **your url** can be any path like path of php file where you can write code to fetch current data.

Comment: can you give me any tutorial for that from where I can read and work?

Comment: What is data here in function?

Comment: @Manwal thanks for giving this code.. I am using this and is working fine. thankyou/./ But I got this after a long tutorial given by DrColossos